# type checking helper with Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want to write a function whose specifications is described in the piece of code below which is the current implementation I have. It does work. However I have been trying for a while to write it pointfree and entirely as a composition of ramda functions and could not find a solution. The issue is linked to `obj => map(key => recordSpec[key](obj[key])` which I cannot reduce in a way that I can write the whole thing pointfree.

How could I do?

`/**
   * check that an object :
   * - does not have any extra properties than the expected ones (strictness)
   * - that its properties follow the defined specs
   * Note that if a property is optional, the spec must include that case
   * @param {Object.<String, Predicate>} recordSpec
   * @returns {Predicate}
   * @throws when recordSpec is not an object
   */
  function isStrictRecordOf(recordSpec) {
    return allPass([
        // 1. no extra properties, i.e. all properties in obj are in recordSpec
        // return true if recordSpec.keys - obj.keys is empty
        pipe(keys, flip(difference)(keys(recordSpec)), isEmpty),
        // 2. the properties in recordSpec all pass their corresponding predicate
        // For each key, execute the corresponding predicate in recordSpec on the 
        // corresponding value in obj
        pipe(obj => map(key => recordSpec[key](obj[key]), keys(recordSpec)), all(identity)),
      ]
    )
  }`

For instance,

`isStrictRecordOf({a : isNumber, b : isString})({a:1, b:'2'}) -> true
isStrictRecordOf({a : isNumber, b : isString})({a:1, b:'2', c:3}) -> false
isStrictRecordOf({a : isNumber, b : isString})({a:1, b:2}) -> false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use [`R.where`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#where), which takes a spec object like your `recordSpec` and applies each predicate with the value from the corresponding keys of the second object.

Your function would then look like:

```
const isStrictRecordOf = recordSpec => allPass([
  pipe(keys, flip(difference)(keys(recordSpec)), isEmpty),
  where(recordSpec)
])
```

Comment: wow, that was shorter than I expected. Many thanks. it is hard to get hold of the numerous ramda functions. Still I wonder, if `where` did not expect, how one would go about writing this point free. But anyways, I am goign to test the answer and accept it if tests pass